# PHP Password Protect page - redirect

Tags: php, password-protection

I am using the PHP password protection snippet from http://www.fullypixel.com/page/tutorials.html/_/fully-pixel-forum-faq/simple-php-password-protection-for-a-single-page-r27 which looks like....

```
<?php    
if (!isset($_POST['txtAccCode']))
{
//If not isset -> set with dummy value
$_POST['txtAccCode'] = "undefine";
}
// Define your user array
$access_codeArray = array("john","paul","george","ringo","b4dh39gsv55x");
$access_code = $_POST['txtAccCode'];
$result = in_array($access_code, $access_codeArray); 
  if ($_POST['txtAccCode'] != $result) {
  ?>
  <style type="text/css">
  #login {margin:0 auto; width:500px;}
  .login {font-family:"Verdana", sans-serif;border:2px solid #3753f5;}
.login p {font-size:13.0px;}
.login p {padding-left:10px;}
h2.login {padding:10px;}
</style>
<div id="login">
<h2 class="login">Enter Access Code to view content</h2>  
<form class="login" name="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">     
<p><label for="txtAccCode">Enter Access Code:</label>    
<br /><input type="text" title="Enter Access Code" name="txtAccCode" /></p>     
<p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login" /></p>  
</form> 
</div> 
<?php  
echo '<script> alert ("Please enter a valid access code to continue.");; </script>';
}  else {  ?>
```

Everything works great but I am now trying to modify it so that it redirects when the correct password is input rather than display hidden content.

Is this something I should be doing in PHP or will I need to use javascript to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In the end of your example, you have `else`, so:

```
// ...
} else {
  header('Location: http://google.com');
  exit;
}
```

Comment: That's because before this line there was something printed out. You have to be sure that there is no `echo` before or plain HTML displayed.

Comment: But that is my original point.  This prints out a login page first so to do the redirection should I be using jQuery instead?

Answer (score 1):

Once the user fulfills the conditions required to be logged,  you should redirect:

```
if(empty($errors) && $_POST)    #not erros, user validated then
        {
 exit(header('Location: logeed_user_landing.php));
}
```